# Update object property after property in BindingList is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, bindinglist

I'm very new to WPF and MVVM and it frustrates me a lot at the moment. My current problem is:

I have the following XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding StreetList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStreet}" DisplayMemberPath="StreetName" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedStreet.HouseList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="YearBuilt" Binding="{Binding YearBuilt}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding Price}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="#Rooms" Binding="{Binding Rooms}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding AvgPricePerRoom, Mode=OneWay}" />
</WrapPanel>
```

where:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public BindingList<StreetViewModel> StreetList { get { return _streetList; } }
    private BindingList<StreetViewModel> _streetList;

    public StreetViewModel SelectedStreet
    {
        get { return _selectedStreet; }
        set { _selectedStreet = (StreetViewModel)value.Clone(); RaisePropertyChanged(); RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(AvgPricePerRoom)); }
    }
    private StreetViewModel _selectedStreet;

    public double AvgPricePerRoom
    {
        get
        {
            return
              _selectedStreet.HouseList[0].Price / _selectedStreet.HouseList[0].Rooms / 3 +
              _selectedStreet.HouseList[1].Price / _selectedStreet.HouseList[1].Rooms / 3 +
              _selectedStreet.HouseList[2].Price / _selectedStreet.HouseList[2].Rooms / 3;
        }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _streetList = new BindingList<StreetViewModel>();
        fill_HouseGroupList();
    }

    void fill_HouseGroupList() { ... }
}
```

and (**EDITED**):

```
public class StreetViewModel : ViewModelBase, ICloneable
{
    public string StreetName
    {
        get { return _streetName; }
        set { _streetName = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
    private string _streetName;


    private BindingList<HouseViewModel> _houseList;

    private void HouseList_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public StreetViewModel() { }

    public StreetViewModel(string streetName) : this()
    {
        _streetName = streetName;

        _houseList = new BindingList<HouseViewModel>();

        HouseList.ListChanged += HouseList_ListChanged;
    }

    public BindingList<HouseViewModel> HouseList
    {
        get
        {
            if(_houseList.Count == 0)
            {
                switch (_streetName)
                {
                    case "Main street":
                        _houseList.Add(new HouseViewModel(new House(2015, 600, 9)));
                        _houseList.Add(new HouseViewModel(new House(1929, 20, 4)));
                        _houseList.Add(new HouseViewModel(new House(1969, 30, 6)));
                        break;
                    case "School street":
                        _houseList.Add(new HouseViewModel(new House(2017, 50, 10)));
                        _houseList.Add(new HouseViewModel(new House(1930, 10, 5)));
                        _houseList.Add(new HouseViewModel(new House(1970, 20, 7)));
                        break;
                    case "Garden street":
                        _houseList.Add(new HouseViewModel(new House(2014, 1, 15)));
                        _houseList.Add(new HouseViewModel(new House(1935, 20, 11)));
                        _houseList.Add(new HouseViewModel(new House(1978, 20, 9)));
                        break;
                }
            }
            return _houseList;
        }
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        var houseGroupCopy = new StreetViewModel(this._streetName);

        houseGroupCopy._houseList = new BindingList<HouseViewModel>();
        foreach (var house in _houseList)
        {
            houseGroupCopy._houseList.Add(new HouseViewModel(new House(house.YearBuilt, house.Price, house.Rooms)));
        }

        return houseGroupCopy;
    }
}
```

plus:

```
public class HouseViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public House House
    {
        get { return _house; }
        set { _house = value;  RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
    private House _house;

    public int YearBuilt
    {
        get { return _house.YearBuilt; }
        set { _house.YearBuilt = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public double Price
    {
        get { return _house.Price; }
        set { _house.Price = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public int Rooms
    {
        get { return _house.Rooms; }
        set { _house.Rooms = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public HouseViewModel(House house)
    {
        _house = house;
    }
}
```

... so in the DataGrid of my view I can edit the properties of the House items in my HouseList which is a BindingList.
How can I make the property AvgPricePerRoom - which is displayed in the TextBox - aware of the changes in the DataGrid, so that the updated AvgPricePerRoom is shown upon changes in the Grid? I have used the BindingList because I read that unlike ObservableCollection it raises an event also when the properties of its items change (performance problems aside), but how do I handle this event and notify my AvgPricePerRoom in this example?

(Not all of the code above is important for my problem, and I am sorry for this...)

Comment: Unrelated tip: rather than `RaisePropertyChanged("AvgPricePerRoom");`, prefer `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(AvgPricePerRoom));`. This avoids having a string representing the property name, and the risk that one might change without changing the other.

Comment: Another tip: caution that the `HouseList` property checks whether `_houseList==null`, and if it is, it tries to call `Add` on the null object. So if that's actually possible, you've got a NullReferenceException coming.

Comment: thanks @Richardissimo, I edited the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When binding collections, there are 3 kinds of Change notiication you must take care off:

1. Notifications for adding/removes from the list. This is the only Notification ObservableCollection actually takes care off.
2. Notifications for the property exposing the ObservableCollection (StreetList in your example). OC are very bad at large scale changes (no AddRange function), so it is often better to create a new list in code, only exposing it as the last step.
3. Change Notification on each property of StreetViewModel.

Comment: My code is probably too nested, but what I am focusing on is the `BindingList<HouseViewModel> HouseList` that is represented by the DataGrid - and there specifically on your point 3. How will the TextBox with `AvgPricePerRoom` always show the updated result based on every change in the DataGrid?

Comment: Once you have proper ChangeNotification in place, the Binding class will take care of the details. All it really does is register the nessesary events on both ends (ViewModel and View) and assigns change to one end on the other one (if TwoWayMode).

Comment: Also you may want to turn AvgPricePerRoom into a full property with a backing field. Right now it is a get-only property with a computed return value, wich requries you to call it's ChangeNotification from someplace else. Instead make a "CalculateAverage" function that calculates the average and assigns it to the Property and have the property raise it's own change notificaiton.

Comment: So I edited the code and my HouseList should now listen to changes in its items through HouseList.ListChanged += HouseList_ListChanged;. However, when the items get edited in the datagrid, the HouseList_ListChanged handler never gets called and I don't understand why.

Comment: I do not see you raising any form of ChangeNotification inside HouseList, or even in the name of HouseList.

Comment: I think your mock code is a big part of the issue. You a creating a example list in the property getter. Not only will that not raise change notification, different callers of the get will even get different instances of the list. You should turn it into a proper get/set pair. Maybe private set. And then have the creation and assignment of the example in another code. A "Load" function if you have any. Or the constructor. As long as those work with the property rather then teh backing field, change notification will take care of the rest.

Comment: I am also not certain if BindingList is the proper type. THere are actually at least two flavors of Binding - the one used in MVVM/Dekstop GUIs. And the one used in ASP.Net. They have nothing in common except the name. Usually we use ObservableCollection[T] and leave all other Change Notification to the Property exposing them, or the elements contained in them. I wrote a intro into MVVM a few years back, based on my own Difficulties in learning it. It might still help you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution although I am not sure if that is the "right way" to do it:

As recommended I turned `AvgPricePerRoom` into a full property with backing field and added a function that sets `AvgPricePerRoom`:

```
void CalculateAverage()
{
    AvgPricePerRoom =
          _selectedStreet.HouseList[0].Price / _selectedStreet.HouseList[0].Rooms / 3 +
          _selectedStreet.HouseList[1].Price / _selectedStreet.HouseList[1].Rooms / 3 +
          _selectedStreet.HouseList[2].Price / _selectedStreet.HouseList[2].Rooms / 3;
}
```

Then I changed the `SelectedStreet` Property to:

```
public StreetViewModel SelectedStreet
{
    get { return _selectedStreet; }
    set
    {
        _selectedStreet = value.Clone() as StreetViewModel;
        CalculateAverage();
        _selectedStreet.HouseList.ListChanged += (o, e) => CalculateAverage();
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Is this a proper MVVM solution?

Comment: I would put the CalculateAverage() after ChangeNotifciation. Otherwise updates might happen in really wierd and contradicting orders. The only other way to do this would be to have StreetViewModel register it's own PropertyChangeNotificaiton. But taht is really just a option change. Carrying code like this is exactly what Properties or Get/Set functions were designed for. That and Inheritance.